# Varying an action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, geodesics

I have to vary the action
$$
S = \dfrac{1}{2}\int d\tau \sigma(\tau)g_{\mu\nu}(X(\tau))\dfrac{dX^\mu}{d\tau}\dfrac{dX^\nu}{d\tau}
$$
with respect to $X$ and I'm supposed to get

$$ \dfrac{d}{d\tau}\left(\sigma g_{\mu\rho} \dfrac{dX^\mu}{d\tau} \right) - \dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu})\sigma \dfrac{dX^\mu}{d\tau} \dfrac{dX^\nu}{d\tau} = 0$$

My understanding is that if we have an action 
$$ S = \int dtL(t, q(t), \dot{q}(t)) $$
then to vary with respect to $q$ we use the Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \right) -  \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial q} = 0$$

So, let $t \rightarrow \tau$ and $L \rightarrow \sigma(\tau) g_{\mu\nu}(X(\tau))\dfrac{dX^\mu}{d\tau} \dfrac{dX^\nu}{d\tau}$ and we have

$$ \dfrac{d}{d\tau}\left(\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \frac{dX^\rho}{d\tau}} \right) = \dfrac{d}{d\tau}\left( \sigma g_{\mu\rho}\dfrac{dX^\mu}{d\tau} \right)$$
and
$$ \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial X^\rho} = \sigma (\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu})\dfrac{dX^\mu}{d\tau}\dfrac{dX^\nu}{d\tau} $$

without the 1/2 on the second term. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got two mistakes:

1. The lagragian is actually: 
   $$
   L \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\times\sigma(\tau) g_{\mu\nu}(X(\tau))\dfrac{dX^\mu}{d\tau} \dfrac{dX^\nu}{d\tau}
   $$
2. The varying of $\dot{X}$ is:
   $$
   \dfrac{d}{d\tau}\left(\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{X}} \right) = 2\times\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{d\tau}\left( \sigma g_{\mu\nu}\dfrac{dX^\mu}{d\tau} \right)
   $$
   where the $2\times$ come from the fact that the lagragian is quadratic on $\dot{X}$.

Then when you vary $X$ you are going to find:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial X^\rho} = \frac{1}{2}\times\sigma (\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}) \frac{dX^\mu}{d\tau} \frac{dX^\nu}{d\tau}
$$
And the equation of motion will be:
$$
\dfrac{d}{d\tau}\left(\sigma g_{\mu\rho} \dfrac{dX^\mu}{d\tau} \right) = \dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu})\sigma \dfrac{dX^\mu}{d\tau} \dfrac{dX^\nu}{d\tau}
$$

Comment: Is the 1/2 on the lagrangian actually relevant? It seems to me that we get the exact same equation for the motion whether we drop it or not.

Comment: @Ian is irrelevant. But once you trhow away the $1/2$ you need to do it consistently.